# require Authentification for change the user in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, forms, dropdown, html-select

Did anyone know how do I require Auth for change the user . I have a dropdown select in my form wild all users an the default user is the auth user
Controller

```
 public function create()
    {   
        $users = User::all();
        $auth = Auth()->user()->name;
        return view('evaluation.create', ['users' => $users, 'auth' => $auth]);
    }
```

and the dropdown in the view

```
<label name="expert">Expert:</label>
<select name="expert">
  <option selected="">{{$auth}}</option>
  @foreach ($users as $user)   
    <option value="{{$user->name}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

So I list al the user and the value is the auth user, but if I want to choose another user I can do it and this is not want I want. I want something like if you want to change the user to send you to the log-in and you have to log in with that user that you selected because the default option is auth user. Thank's !

Comment: basically you want to display the logged in username, if the user is authenticated the select box should be disabled? and if no authorised user,the we can select any username?

Comment: No,  In my select box I have all users displayed and if I want to choose another user wich is not the authenticated user it's should  send me to login to log with that user and his name will appear instead because the selected option is the authenticated  user. I don't want to disable the select box.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use `id` as value in the select box because it's unique among all users. then you can use `auth()->login()` to set the user. then your code should be like this:

the html part:

```
<form method="post" action="/somewhere">
<label name="expert">Expert:</label>
<select name="expert">
  <option selected="">{{$auth}}</option>
  @foreach ($users as $user)   
    <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
</form>
```

the route part:

```
route::post('somewhere', 'SomeController@switch')->middleware('auth');
```

the controller part:

```
function switch(Request $request) {
    auth()->loginUsingId($request->get('expert'));
    // or use this: auth()->login(User::findOrFail($request->get('expert')));
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

but this code is extremely vulnerable, you should use validation and some more checking on values and privileges.